# Use form_validator to check that the email is the same

Tags: flutter

I'm using the [`form_validator`](https://pub.dev/packages/form_validator) Flutter plugin to create a form block.
My form contains contains a lot of fields including `Email` and `Email confirmation`:

```dart
TextFormField(
  validator: ValidationBuilder()
      .email()
      .maxLength(50)
      .required()
      .build(),
  decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'email'),
),
const SizedBox(height: 30),

TextFormField(
  validator: ValidationBuilder()
      .email()
      .maxLength(50)
      .required()
      .build(),
  decoration:
      const InputDecoration(labelText: 'email confirmation'),
),
```

They are equals, the only thing that changes is the label. How can I add a check to the second field (`EMAIL CONFIRMATION`) that controls that it's the same value of the first one?

Example:

```
EMAIL: john.snow@gmail.com
EMAIL CONFIRMATION: john.snow@gmail.com
--> ok

EMAIL: john.snow@gmail.com
EMAIL CONFIRMATION: harry.potter@gmail.com
--> error
```

Comment: The package you are using may not support that out of the box. Therefore, you can simply use the [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) property of the `TextFormField` to compare the values and adjust the UI as necessary. Have you looked at the package API to see if this is built in?

Comment: @daddygames thank you for the reply. I found the [or function](https://pub.dev/documentation/form_validator/latest/form_validator/ValidationBuilder/or.html) that maybe can help but I'm not sure and I don't know how to use it

Comment: From a quick look at `ValidationBuilder.or`, it appears that it does one validation or another. It doesn't do any kind of compare against the values. I'm not sure that will solve your issue.

Comment: @daddygames mmm ok. what do you suggest to do? how could i quickly use onChanged property and modify the ui?

Comment: I recommend using the [CustomValidationBuilder](https://pub.dev/packages/form_validator#extending-validationbuilder) option of the package you are using. It will give you the flexibility you need without having to resort to `onChanged` or something like that. You'll want to add `TextEditingController`s to your `TextFormField`s so that you can compare the 2 values inside your custom validator. If I can find a moment to write an example, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @daddygames thank you! It will be very useful

Comment: why dont you build your own form?

Comment: @Nbn I have not much time and would like to use something more robust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use 2 text controllers like say,

> emailTextController

> confirmEmailTextController

Make sure you add the following validator method in the `Confirm Email` TextFormField

```
validator: (value) {
    if (value != emailTextController.text) {
        return 'Email is not matching';
    }
},
```

And you get the respective errorText, whose fontStyle can be adjusted.